# What do commas and spaces in multiple classes mean in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is an example that I do not understand:

```
.container_12 .grid_6,
.container_16 .grid_8 {
    width: 460px;
}
```

It seems to me that `width: 460px` is applied to all above mentioned classes. But why some classes are separated by a comma (`,`), and some just by a space?

I assume that `width: 460px` will be applied only to those elements which combine classes in the way mentioned in the CSS file. For example, it will be applied to `<div class='container_12 grid_6'>` but it will not be applied to the `<div class='container_12'>`. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but I'd like to offer a recommendation to try SASS. It looks like you're going to have a ton of duplicated CSS, considering the class names.

Comment: @Roman There could also be ` .container_12 .grid_6.line ` Notice, no space between grid_6 and line; this implies the element should have both grid_6 and line as classes. And it should be a child of 'container', as @Sampson points out in the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 224, accepted):

```
.container_12 .grid_6,
.container_16 .grid_8 {
    width: 460px;
}
```

That says "make all .grid_6's within .container_12's and all .grid_8's within .container_16's 460 pixels wide." So both of the following will render the same:

```
<div class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_6">460px Wide</div>
</div>
<div class="container_16">
  <div class="grid_8">460px Wide</div>
</div>
```

As for the commas, it's applying one rule to multiple classes, like this.

```
.blueCheese, .blueBike {
  color:blue;
}
```

It's functionally equivalent to:

```
.blueCheese { color:blue }
.blueBike { color:blue }
```

But cuts down on verbosity.

Comment: I understand that we can apply one rule to several classes separated by comas. It's not clear to me why some classes in the example are not separated by commas.

Comment: When they are separated by a space, it's a nesting issue. The latter are found within the former. So `.container_12 .grid_6` is addressing only the `.grid_6` items found within `.container_12` items.

Comment: will it work for nested classes under the two different parent? @Sampson

Answer (score 44):

```
.container_12 .grid_6 { ... }
```

This rule matches a DOM node with class `container_12` that has a descendant (not necessarily a child) with class `grid_6`, and applies the CSS rules to the DOM element with class `grid_6`.

```
.container_12 > .grid_6 { ... }
```

Putting `>` between them says that the `grid_6` node must be a direct child of the node with class `container_12`.

```
.container_12, .grid_6 { ... }
```

A comma, as others have stated, is a way to apply rules to many different nodes at one time. In this case, the rules apply to any node with either a class of `container_12` or `grid_6`.

Answer (score 27):

Not exactly what was asked, but maybe this will help.

To apply a style to an element only if it has both classes your selector should use no space between the class names.

For Example:

```css
.class1.class2 { color: #f00; }
.class1 .class2 { color: #0f0; }
.class1, .class2 { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div class='class1 class2'>Bold Red Text</div>
<div class='class1'>Bold Text (not red)</div>
<div class='class1'><div class='class2'>Bold Green Text</div></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

**Comma** groups the classes (applies the same style to them all), **an empty space** tells that the following selector must be within the first selector.

Therefore

```
.container_12 .grid_6,
.container_16 .grid_8 {
    width: 460px;
}
```

applies that style to only class `.grid_6` which is within `.container_12` class and to `.grid_8` class which is within `.container_16`.

Answer (score 6):

The `width: 460px;` will be applied to the element with the `.grid_8` class, contained *inside* the elements with `.container_16` class, and elements with the `.grid_6` class, contained *inside* the elements with `.container_12`.

The space means heritage, and the comma means 'and'. If you put properties with a selector like `.class-a, .class-b`, you will have the properties applied to the elements with anyone of the two classes.

Answer (score 4):

The above means that you are applying styles to two classes, indicated by the comma.

When you see two elements side by side not separated you can assume that it is referring to an area within an area.  So in the above, this style only applies to grid_6 classes inside of container_12 classes and grid_8 classes inside of container_16 classes.

in the example:

```
<div class="grid_6">This is not effected</div>
<div class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_6">
    This is effected.
  </div>
</div>
```

The first grid_6 will not be effected while the second grid_6 class will because it is contained inside a container_12.

A statement like

```
#admin .description p { font-weight:bold; }
```

Would only apply the bold to

tags within areas that have class "description" that are inside of an area with id "admin", such as:

```
<div id="admin">
   <div class="description">
      <p>This is bold</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have four classes and two selectors in your example:

```
.container_12 .grid_6,
.container_16 .grid_8 {
    width: 460px;
}
```

So `.container_12` and `.grid_6` are both classes, but the rule `width: 460px` will only be applied to elements that have the `.grid_6` class which are descendants of an element that have the `.container_16` class.

For example:

```
<div class="container_16">
<p class=".grid_6">This has a width of 480px.</p>
<p>This has an unknown width.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Selectors combinations get different meanings - attached image explains easily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN4C6.png)

a) Multiple selectors separated by a comma(`,`) - Same styles are applied to all selected elements.

```
div,.elmnt-color {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here border style is applied to `DIV` elements and CSS class `.elmnt-color` applied elements.

```
<!-- comma example -->
<div>
  Red border applied
</div>
<p class="elmnt-color">
  Red border applied
</p>
```

b) Multiple selectors separated by space – Those are called descendant selectors.

```
div .elmnt-color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here border style is applied to CSS class `.elmnt-color` applied elements which are **child** elements of a `DIV` element.

```
<!-- space example -->
<div>
  Red border NOT applied
</div>
<p class="elmnt-color">
  Red border NOT applied
</p>
<div>
  Red border NOT applied    
  <p class="elmnt-color">
    Red border applied
  </p>
</div>
```

c) Multiple selectors specified without space - Here styles are applied to elements which meet all the combinations.

```
div.elmnt-color {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here border style is applied only to `DIV` elements with a CSS class of `.elmnt-color`.

```
<!-- no space example -->
<div>
  Red border NOT applied
</div>
<p class="elmnt-color">
  Red border NOT applied
</p>
<div>
  Red border NOT applied    
  <p class="elmnt-color">
    Red border NOT applied
  </p>
</div>
<div class="elmnt-color">
  Red border applied
</div>
```

Details are attached at https://www.csssolid.com/css-tips.html

Note: CSS Class is just one of the CSS Selectors. These rules applies to **all** CSS Selectors (ex: Class, Element, ID etc.,).

Answer (score 1):

```
.container_12 .grid_6,
.container_16 .grid_8 {
    width: 460px;
}
```

`width:460px` will be only applied to `.grid_6` and `.grid_8`

**Edit: Here is a very good article for you**

http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Comment: Only if `.grid_6` & `.grid_8` resides within a `.container_12` or `.container_16`

Comment: @sshow - Thanks. you are right but that is a HTML issue. according to this css code my answer is right