# In CSS3, what does a comma between declaration blocks mean?

Tags: css, minify, clean-css

Yes yes, we all know what a [comma between **selectors**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344284/what-do-commas-and-spaces-in-multiple-classes-mean-in-css) means.

This is different.  I thought I knew CSS pretty well, but today I came across something I've never seen before - a comma **between declaration blocks**.  I've been using [clean-css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css), and it generated this minified, cleaned output (I've re-inserted some whitespace for readability):

```
body .container
{
    color:#EEE
}
,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
h1
{
    color:#000
}
```

Notice the comma (which I've placed on its own line) after the closing curly brace in the declaration block for `body .container`.  Is this valid CSS?  If so, what does it mean?

My input CSS for clean-css was as follows:

```
body .container {
  color: #EEEEEE;
}

h1{
  color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: I believe that is invalid CSS.

Comment: I want to thank you for asking this question, as I discovered an exclude-IE8-only selector set hack, and a bug in current versions of Chrome/Firefox/Edge because of it. Try a `.selector, #excludeIE8::before` in IE8, or a `.selector, .selector::future-pseudo` in Chrome/Firefox/Edge haha

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to advance the knowledge of IE8 hacks, and thus the collective knowledge of humanity as a whole ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not valid CSS. A comma in that position implies that there is an empty selector preceding it. But an empty selector is not a selector at all; a selector must contain, at the very minimum, either a simple selector or a pseudo-element (with an implicit `*`). From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax):

> An empty selector, containing no sequence of simple selectors and no pseudo-element, is an invalid selector.

This may be the result of a bug in clean-css. Alternatively, the input CSS was invalid to begin with and this was simply the result of clean-css's attempt to process it.

Comment: Why the hell would anyone use that XD

Comment: Ah ha!  It would appear there was indeed some potentially invalid input CSS.  There was a rule `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, { ... }` - notice the comma between the last selector and the beginning of the declaration block.  My apprentice designer still has some things to learn ;-)

I'll look more into clean-css and see if they have some kind of `strict` option for catching something like this.

Comment: Should note that this can also be used as a hack to make an entire rule only load in LTE IE 7, as all other browsers (even IE 8, sadly) will throw out the entire rule regardless of the validity of any other selector(s) for it.