# Is placing commas between multiple CSS ID Selectors ok?

Tags: css

What is correct:

```
#pears, #apples, #peaches
```

or

```
#pears #apples #peaches
```

Difference is the commas between them...

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do commas and spaces in multiple classes mean in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344284/what-do-commas-and-spaces-in-multiple-classes-mean-in-css)

Comment: the second one i.e. #pears #apples #peaches is only possible if apples is a child of pears and peaches is the child of apples

Comment: the first one is: `get me the #pears-node, the #apples-node and the #peaches-node` the second one is: `get me the #peaches-node inside the #apples-node inside the #pears-node`. So, no, `,` are not optional in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is correct, you can legitimately comma separate those selectors

EDITED: @ovokuro is correct BOTH are correct.

The first example would apply a style to three different elements with those three ID's

The second would target the last ID, which is a child of the ID before, which is also a child of the ID before.

Comment: The second is also correct, depending on what you want to target

Answer (score 0):

use commas for example :

```
#pears a, #apples a, #peaches a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma is used to make a group of selectors while spaces are used to select any child that match the next selector.

By placing commas it will make a group of all the selected elements and will apply the style to whole group(`#pears`, `#apples`, `#peaches`), while using spaces it means select `#peaches` inside `#apples` that is the child of `#pears` and the style will only be applied to `#peaches`.