# Why is there a border showing on my table?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table created with html/css:

```
<div id="test">
    <table class="test-table">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="test-header">
            <td>
                <label>Name</label>
                <div>Bob</div>
            </td>
            <td class="middle-cell">
                <label>Number</label>
                <div>1</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Date</label>
                <div>Today</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And I have some simple `css`

```
.xxxxx > th, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This is showing the border on my table, even though there isn't a `class` `xxxxx` in my `html`.  How and why is this showing?  If I wanted to scope the border to the `th`, `tr`, and `td` in this specific `table`, how would I do that?

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139781/3569921

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do commas and spaces in multiple classes mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344284/what-do-commas-and-spaces-in-multiple-classes-mean-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS should be like shown below.

**Reason:**

You are using grouping selectors (*You can apply a style to many selectors if you like. Just separate the selectors with a comma*), but its doesn't work like grouping all the children of a parent selector (`.class > a, p, br`) but it should be like (`.class > a, .class > p, .class > br`)

```css
.xxxxx > tr, .xxxxx > td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <table class="test-table">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="test-header">
            <td>
                <label>Name</label>
                <div>Bob</div>
            </td>
            <td class="middle-cell">
                <label>Number</label>
                <div>1</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Date</label>
                <div>Today</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You get the same result if you just remove tr and td in your child selector since you don't define a th in your code displayed.