# h1{} and h1, h1{} differences on css

Tags: html, css

I would like to know what the differences between (it always choose pink and green):

```
h1 {color:red;}
h1, h1 {color:pink;}
p {color:blue;}
p, p {color:green;}
```

Moreover in this example the hover does not work

```
a, a:visited {
color:green;
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
}

a:hover{
color: red;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do commas and spaces in multiple classes mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344284/what-do-commas-and-spaces-in-multiple-classes-mean-in-css)

Comment: Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply rules to multiple selectors using `,`
for instance.

```
h1, p { color: red; }
```

Here you are doing.

```
h1, h1 { color: red; }
```

Above code will set red color to both `h1` and `h1` elements,but as both are same selector, the second selector will be useless.

The only reason you have pink `h1` is because the last rule wins when the specificity is the same.

```
h1, h1 {color:pink;}
h1 {color:red;}
```

This would give a red color to `h1`.